# SQL Server : comparing VARCHAR values

Tags: sql-server, compare

I'm trying to compare month and year only. So I convert it to varchar. Is this correct?

```
(case 
    when s."AccMonth" >= 1 and s."AccMonth" <= 12 
        then cast(rtrim(s.accmonth) + s.accyear AS varchar) end)
>=  
cast(month(s.InitialChargeDate) as varchar) + cast(year(s.InitialChargeDate) as varchar)
```

- `accmonth` & `accyear` are of type `INT`
- `InitialChargeDate` is of type `DATE`

Comment: I'm not 100% clear on the final result you want, but take a look at the datepart function: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174420.aspx

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps a better way to do it would be something like:

```
s.AccMonth = MONTH(s.InitialChargeDate)
AND s.accyear = YEAR(s.InitialChargeDate)
```

Note: When casting to a varchar without a length specification, the default length is 1.  That may be affecting your results.

Comment: OK, what do you mean by "comparing"?  The slice of code I posted compares; it just does it without concatenation.

Comment: When casting to a varchar without a length specification, the default length is 30.

Answer (score 0):

You should use built-in functions instead of casting to varchar:

[Month](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187813.aspx):

```
SELECT MONTH('2007-04-30T01:01:01.1234567 -07:00');
```

Returns 4

[Year](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186313.aspx):

```
SELECT YEAR('2007-04-30T01:01:01.1234567-07:00');
```

Returns 2007